# Vim exec command in command line, and Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Tags: vim

**vi.sh**

```
vim -c "set ft=unix" -c "x" $1
```

**main.sh**

```
sh vi.sh file1
sh vi.sh file2
```

If I exec `sh vi.sh file1` or `sh main.sh`, there is no warning.

But if I exec `cat main.sh | sh`, it would give:`Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`.

What is the difference? How can I dismiss this warning message when I run `cat main.sh | sh`?

Comment: Why do you want to `cat main.sh` into `sh`? Why not just `./main.sh`?

Comment: It is `bzcat *` actually...If `cat` work,`bzcat` should work too. Just use `cat` for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim Input is not from a terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281304/vim-input-is-not-from-a-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `~/bin/r`

```
[ $# -eq 0 ] && set -- -;
vim -R "$@"
```

in my `.vimrc`:

```
au StdinReadPost * set buftype=nofile
```

Comment: `set --` sets the parameters to the rest of the parms

Answer (score 2):

You've to do pseudo-tty allocation.
Try something like (`vi.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec vim -c "set ft=unix" -c "x" "$@" < /dev/tty
```

Related:

- [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE

Comment: not sure why the extra parameters, `exec vim [files] </dev/tty` works fine

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to suppress the warning.

**main.sh**

```
sh vi.sh file1 2>/dev/null
sh vi.sh file2 2>/dev/null
```

But note that it actually suppresses all warnings.

The reason is probably that Vim found your pipe is opened while the Vim command was not to read anything from `stdin`. So the warning is just like a reminder.

So a better solution is to save the commands somewhere, e.g. **make.sh** itself and launch it.

Another question about this issue here
https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why