# Vim Input is not from a terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

```
which django-admin.py | vim
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
```

What is the easiest way to fix this? And actually make vim to open "`/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`"

Essentially I want to host an auto-install customized vim on my personal blog: http://wayneye.com/vim, you can see the shell script by navigating to it, it just contains the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim \
curl -L -o ~/.vimrc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WayneYe/WayneDevLab/master/wayne.vimrc \
vim +PluginInstall
```

But when I do curl http://wayneye.com/vim | sh, I got the "**input not from terminal error**", how can I fix that please?

Comment: Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE

Comment: `which django-admin.py | xargs -o vim`

Answer (score 24):

In order for you to read from `stdin` you need to tell VIM explicitly to do that by using the `-` parameter at the commandline.

So in your case, this should work:

```
which django-admin.py | vim -
```

Quick question though, when you use `which` with a filename, do you expect it to show you the path or is `django-admin.py` an executable that exists in path? In which case, you're fine.

Comment: This works, one more question sir, I want to host an auto-install customized vim on my personal blog: http://wayneye.com/vim, you can see the shell script there, when I do curl http://wayneye.com/vim | sh, I got the "input not from terminal error", how can I fix that please?

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. Let me look into this and get back to you :) In the meanwhile, consider accepting this as an answer if it helped you out.

Comment: I actually revised my question, because run the vim installation sh is really what I want.

Comment: this opens the standard input as a text file, e.g. `echo 1 | vim -` will open a text file named "-stdin-" with "1" as the content

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following:

```
% vim "$(which django-admin.py)"
```

It should work, as long as `django-admin.py` is actually found by `which` command and it is not aliased.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way to do this:

```
vim `which django-admin.py`
```

Comment: I actually know this, but I cannot solve the problem of "curl wayneye.com/vim | sh"